# Как использовать sqlalchemy с уже разаботанной базой

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Не давно начал использовать ORM для разработки приложения, но возник вопрос: как быть если ее нужно подключить к уже готовой базе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ, через рефлексию:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=True)
# echo=True позволяет в консоли видеть применяемые к базе запросы
metadata = sa.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
users_table = metadata.tables('users')
addresses_table = metadata.tables('addresses')

sa.select([users_table, addresses_table])
```

более сложный, но понятный в дальнейшем, создать описание модели:

```
sequences = Table('sequences', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String),
)
```

Но это пока не ORM, а ядро, которое позволяет формировать запрос средствами языка:

```
statement = sa.sql.select([marker.c.x1, marker.c.x2]) \
    .where(marker.c.x3 == 5) \
    .where(marker.c.x1.in_([1, 5]))
```

Если хотите работать с объектами, придется писать мапперы. Это несложно, похоже на описание таблицы выше, но выходит за рамки вопрос-ответ.